# Concernant l'usage du pluriel après « de » dans « les sites de police/s » ?

Tags: prépositions, pluriel, compléments

On dit *les sites de polices* ou *les sites de police* et s'il vous plait pourquoi ?

Answer (score 4):

#### Cas de l'exemple

« De police » est un groupe prépositionnel ayant ici le rôle de complément du nom.

L'accord en nombre du groupe prépositionnel ne dépend pas de celui du groupe nominal complet. Selon les contextes, les quatre combinaisons suivantes peuvent être valides :

- le site de police ;
- le site de polices ;
- les sites de police ;
- les sites de polices.

Ceci va dépendre de la signification de la phrase. Par exemple, si on parle de la police en tant que force de l'ordre, au singulier, l'exemple sera « le site de (la) police ». Dans le cas (qui correspond davantage à la question, je suppose) où on parle de polices d'écriture, chaque site en propose plusieurs : c'est un « site de police**s** ».

Au pluriel, cela ne change pas : dans le premier cas, on a « des sites de police » tandis que le second donne « des sites de polices ».

Je crains que mon exemple utilisant les forces de l'ordre ne soit pas très convaincant car on a du mal à voir de quoi il peut s'agir, mais il y a un autre exemple bien plus juste dans mon énoncé : j'ai parlé des « polices d'**écriture** ». Bien qu'il y ait plusieurs polices, elles servent toute à l'écriture, une action abstraite et à ce titre s'écrivant au singulier.

#### Règles générales

La page http://bv.alloprof.qc.ca/f1486.aspx résume très bien les principales règles. Je me permets de la citer ici avec les exemples.

> **Le nom du groupe prépositionnel** complément du nom reste au **singulier** quand il désigne l'espèce, la classe, la matière ou la nature d'une chose, ou encore quand il fait référence à une entité abstraite ou une réalité non comptable.
>
> 1. Cent kilos de **beurre**
> 2. Un zeste de **citron**
> 3. Un jeu de **mémoire**
> 4. Les pommes de **terre**
>
> ---
>
> **Le nom du groupe prépositionnel complément du nom** prend la marque du **pluriel** quand il implique nécessairement plusieurs éléments.
>
> 1. Un paquet de **couches**
> 2. Une base de **données**
> 3. Un pot de **fleurs**
> 4. Une mèche de **cheveux**
>
> ---
>
> Lorsque **le nom du groupe prépositionnel** peut être unique ou multiple, son accord peut être au **singulier** ou au **pluriel**.
>
> 1. Une salle de bain / Une salle de bains
> 2. Une pomme sans pépin / Une pomme sans pépins

---

<sub>Sur le même site, on peut retrouver un résumé des différents rôles possibles pour le groupe prépositionnel : http://bv.alloprof.qc.ca/f1482.aspx</sub>

Comment: Je parle dans mon cas de *police* comme autorité et non les caractères ....

Comment: Donc force de l'ordre ...

Comment: @Ojiryx Dans ce cas, la police est une entité non comptable et devrait être au singulier. On parle des commissariat**s** de **police**, par exemple.

Comment: Il peut y avoir plusieurs polices (municipale, de l'université, nationale...). Il y avait donc plusieurs Polices... mais cela reste un cas très particulier et n'est donc utilisé que dans un cas très précis, visant explicitement à différencier les différentes hiérarchies de Police...